# How to set the connection string for a Service Bus Logic App action in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I'm attempting to deploy an Azure Logic App that includes an action to Send a message on a Service Bus using an ARM template.

In addition to deploying the Logic App, the ARM template deploys a Service Bus Namespace, a Queue and two AuthorizationRule (one for sending and one for listening).

I want to dynamically set the connection information for the Send Service Bus Message action to use the Connection string generated for the AuthorizationRule that supports sending.

When I create this in the portal editor (specifying the connection string for sending), I noticed the following is generated in code view...

```
"Send_message.": {
    "conditions": [
        {
            "dependsOn": "<previous action>"
        }
    ],
    "inputs": {
        "body": {
            "ContentData": "@{encodeBase64(triggerBody())}"
        },
        "host": {
            "api": {
                "runtimeUrl": "https://logic-apis-westus.azure-apim.net/apim/servicebus"
            },
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(string('<queuename>'))}/messages"
    },
    "type": "apiconnection"
}
```

},

I assume that the connection information is somehow buried in `@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"`

I then used [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com/) to navigate to the logic app to see if I could get more details as to how `@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"` is defined.

I found this:

```
"parameters": {
  "$connections": {
    "value": {
      "servicebus": {
        "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subguid>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus",
        "connectionName": "servicebus",
        "id": "/subscriptions/<subguid>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westus/managedApis/servicebus"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I still don't see where the connection string is set.

Where can I set the connection string for the service bus action in an ARM template using something like the following?

```
[listkeys(variables('sendAuthRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryConnectionString]
```

EDIT: Also, I've referred to was seems to be [a promising Azure quick start on github (based on the title)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-alert-to-queue-with-logic-app), but I can't make any sense of it.  It appears to use an older schema `2014-12-01-preview`, and the "queueconnector" references an Api Gateway.  If there is a newer example out there for this scenario, I'd love to see it.

Comment: As you know connections is a resource so it needs to be created first did you refer this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh/. Quick start link you are referring is for older schema.

Comment: Thanks Tushar.  It took me a while, but I was able to get the ARM template working using the info in that link.  Happy to give you credit for the answer if you want to submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: Paul please feel free to edit my answer to add more information so that your learning could benefit others. Also I will share the information with my team to add more documentation details.

Comment: Will do.  I plan on submitting a pull request for this scenario to the Azure quickstart templates on github.  I'll add more details to the answer and post the link to the template hopefully sometime this week.

Comment: i hope you did see this template  https://github.com/jeffhollan/logicapps-deployments/blob/master/ftp_to_blob.json

Comment: Yes, I did.  That's the one I was thinking about updating.  I think the .md file on that template should talk more about how you could use this as a reference for other connectors by following the steps here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh/ in order to obtain the required parameters for whatever connector you'd like.  I'd also just add the SB connector to it in some way since I've just done it so that other's don't have to jump through as many hoops if they want to use SB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know connections is a resource so it needs to be created first did you refer this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh/. Quick start link you are referring is for older schema.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently worked on an ARM Template for the deployment of logic apps and service bus connection. Here is the sample template for configuring service bus connection string within the type "Microsoft.Web/connections". Hope it helps.

```
 {
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
    "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
    "name": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_name')]",
    "location": "centralus",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/AuthorizationRules', parameters('ServiceBusNamespace'), 'RootManageSharedAccessKey')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "displayName": "ServiceBusConnection",
      "customParameterValues": {},
      "api": {
        "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus')]"
      },
      "parameterValues": {
        "connectionString": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/authorizationRules', parameters('ServiceBusNamespace'), 'RootManageSharedAccessKey'), '2017-04-01').primaryConnectionString]"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Didn't you miss the "subscriptions/" prefix in the properties/api/id entry? To have it like: [concat('subscriptions/', subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus')]"