# Is it possible to create an Azure Blob Storage Connector using a ARM template or a script?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I'm creating a logic app which will do some operations on a blob storage, thus it needs a Connector to a specific blob storage. I'm able to define which Connector should be used (providing its name and other properties), however if it doesn't exist yet, the template fails to deploy. I know we can create these connectors via logic app designer, but i would very much like to automate that process. Hence the question:

Is it possible to deploy/create this connector using an ARM template or a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this post related to [Logic App connector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750315/4167200).

Here is an ARM Template that create an API connection to blob storage:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "azureBlobConnectionAPIName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the connection api to access the azure blob storage."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Storage Account Name."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "name": "[parameters('azureBlobConnectionAPIName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('azureBlobConnectionAPIName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "accountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
          "accessKey": "[listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]"
        },
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('defaultResourceLocation'), '/managedApis/azureblob')]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the line:
`[listKeys(variables('storageAccountId'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]`
works? Is this the same as putting the key into a parameter? Will this line always work?

Comment: doing this, you tell the ARM template to retrieve internally the key for you so you dont have to pass it as a parameter. It should always work. Just be aware that `2015-05-01-preview` is the version of the ARM resource so if you use a different version, the implementation could be dfferent. check the documentation for more information