# How to create MS Flow/Azure Logic App connection programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

To configure MS Flow/Logic App we need to create connection manually. For example, to create connection with Office 365, need to login with required credentials and connection is created.
Is it possible to create MS Flow/Azure Logic App connection programmatically?

Comment: have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733941/arm-template-office-365-connection-for-logic-apps

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a script on Github](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth) which would allow you to do it programmatically. Still requires user interaction, though.